# Passing Password Value in SQL Query?

Tags: php

How do we pass passwords in a PHP in the QUERY.

I am trying something like this, but i get a syntax error.

`$query = "INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, password) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['fullname']."','".$_REQUEST['userid']."','"$_REQUEST['mailid']."','".$_REQUEST['userpassword']."')";`

There is some error in the above code, which i am unable to figure out. I believe, the password can not be sent simply like this.

Here is the Error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_REQUEST' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the string being a password, it's a simple syntax error that should be highlighted by any syntax-aware editor. Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I second DCoders advice on PDO. Also, I highly recommend that you read up on one-way hash encryption for passwords if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Error in:

`'"$_REQUEST['mailid']`

change on

`'" . $_REQUEST['mailid']`

And

1. Better way to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for insert data received from user to the database;
2. Use [md5() PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) for store password, don't store it without encoding in real form;

Comment: And `password` must be `\`password\`` because it's reserved word in SQL.

Comment: I would recommend bcrypt instead of md5 for password storage instead.

Comment: If you use MD5 to hash passwords, you might as well keep them in plain text.